# How to prevent a long break when using align with both single-line and multi-line (aligned) equations?

Tags: equations, align, alignment

I have the following code which produces two aligned equations: one is a single line long, while the other one uses `aligned` to have several lines.

```
\begin{align}
  W' &= W \cup W^\star &\text{donde } \left| W^\star \right| = \left| W \right| \text{ y } W \cap W^\star = \varnothing \\
  R' &=
    \begin{aligned}[t]
      &\left\{ \left< u, v \right> \mid u \neq v \wedge u \operatorname{R} v \right\} \\
      \cup &\left\{ \left< f(u), f(v) \right> \mid u \neq v \wedge u \operatorname{R} v \right\} \\
      \cup &\left\{ \left< u, f(u) \right> \mid u \operatorname{R} u \right\} \\
      \cup &\left\{ \left< f(u), u \right> \mid u \operatorname{R} u \right\}
    \end{aligned}
    &\text{donde } f : M \to W
\end{align}
```

The result is this image, there is a big break after `W'` so that it has the same height as `R'`.

[image: A LaTeX equation]

Strangely, this doesn't happen if I don't align the second column (`donde ...`).

How can I prevent this big vertical space from happening? Both lines should be reasonable close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can unfortunately happen when the equation number has to be moved down because it can't fit the line.

Solution: do a bit of backspacing.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
W' &= W \cup W^\star 
  &\hspace{-4em}\text{donde } \lvert W^\star \rvert = \lvert W \rvert \text{ y } W \cap W^\star = \varnothing \\
R' &=
    \begin{aligned}[t]
      &\{ \langle u, v \rangle \mid u \neq v \wedge u \mathrel{\mathrm{R}} v \} \\
      &\cup \{ \langle f(u), f(v) \rangle \mid u \neq v \wedge u \mathrel{\mathrm{R}} v \} \\
      &\cup \{ \langle u, f(u) \rangle \mid u \mathrel{\mathrm{R}} u \} \\
      &\cup \{ \langle f(u), u \rangle \mid u \mathrel{\mathrm{R}} u \}
    \end{aligned}
    &\hspace{-4em}\text{donde } f : M \to W
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I removed *all* `\left` and `\right` that in the particular situation only add unwanted space. I also modified the four-line set description to a more standard appearance.

[image]

Comment: That makes sense; I'm using a weird equatino numbering scheme that's invisible in this case so I didn't see the problems with the number.
Just making the second column less wide by using `gathered` worked as fine as this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mathrlap` command (from `mathtools`) in the longest line.

However, I think the two explanations starting with *donde* do not need to be aligned, and I propose a better-looking layout, with a simpler code, after we've defined the `\set` and `\innerp` commands, which require  `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` command (again from `mathtools`) and `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\allowbreak #2\nonscript\,}}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\innerp}[1]{\langle}{\rangle}{\innpargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innpargs}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m }
 {\innpargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innpargsaux}{ m m }
 {#1\,,#2}%

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  W' &= W \cup W^\star & & \text{donde } \left| W^\star \right| = \left| W \right| \text{ y } W \cap W^\star = \varnothing \\
  R' &=
    \begin{aligned}[t]
      &\left\{ \left< u, v \right> \mid u \neq v \wedge u \operatorname{R} v \right\} \\
      \cup &\mathrlap{\left\{ \left< f(u), f(v) \right> \mid u \neq v \wedge u \operatorname{R} v \right\}} \\
      \cup &\left\{ \left< u, f(u) \right> \mid u \operatorname{R} u \right\} \\
      \cup &\left\{ \left< f(u), u \right> \mid u \operatorname{R} u \right\}
    \end{aligned}
    & & \text{donde } f : M \to W
\end{align}
\vskip 2ex
\begin{align}
  W' &= W \cup W^\star, \qquad \text{donde } \left| W^\star \right| = \left| W \right| \text{ y } W \cap W^\star = \varnothing \\
  R' &=
    \begin{aligned}[t]
  &\set[\big]{\innerp{u, v } ; u \neq v \wedge u \operatorname{R} v } \\
 & \cup \set[\big]{\innerp{f(u), f(v) } ; u \neq v \wedge u \operatorname{R} v } \qquad
 \text{donde } f : M \to W\\
 & \cup \set[\big]{\innerp{u, f(u) } ; u \operatorname{R} u } \cup \set[\big]{\innerp{f(u), u} \mid u \operatorname{R} u }
    \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]